# SharePoint 2010 defaultproxy settings bypasslist for web services

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

This is the case:

- Farm with one WFE and one APP-server. WFE hosts all sites, APP-server hosts all SharePoint web services. Names of servers: SPWFE01 and SPAPP01
- WFE can connect to internet through proxy.
- Web services should be bypassed, thus not called through proxy

Thus, I configured web.config as following:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefaults="false" proxyaddress="http://proxy"     bypassonlocal="false" />
        <bypasslist>
            <add address="spwfe01"/>
            <add address="spapp01"/>
            <add address="139\.156\..*"/> <!-- IP-address range of Farm -->
            <add address="10\.246\..*"/> <!-- backup IP-address range of Farm -->
        </bypasslist>            
   </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>
```

However, I get null reference exceptions when I call the UPA from code behind. When I remove above configuration, everything works as expected. Thus, web service calls are made through proxy, despite of bypasslist.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, fixed it by removing usesystemdefaults-attribute...

According to MSDN:

usesystemdefault
Specifies whether to use Internet Explorer proxy settings. If set to true, subsequent attributes will override Internet Explorer proxy settings. The default value is unspecified.

Thus, now it is "unspecified". I have no idea what unspecified is for a boolean value, but it works...